# How to fix this broken floor

Tags: hardwood-floor

My wooden floor has a broken plank,

[image]

There is a vertical supporting wedge in the upper side, I guess I can nail directly onto it, but what I should do about the lower side?

Comment: When you say lower side are you talking about the rotted joyce?

Comment: yeah, not sure the right word for it. @EdBeal

Comment: How do I prevent wood plank from rotting by the way? I assume all of them would have been treated, but they ended up rotting anyway. So treating them would only slow down the rotting process?

Comment: Regular application of a water seal or a paint will extend the life but wood exposed to the elements will have a life span based on the conditions, regular maintenance can extend the life greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The floor joists are rotted in that particular area. It could be the same all over. The only thing you could try is to remove some more of the decking and "sister" the joists (Nail a second joist alongside the old one). This will give you some new area to nail your decking. You might be looking at replacing this deck in the near future. If all of the joists look like that, someone could get hurt.